# SQL Query Designer

Tags: sql-server, syntax, mysql

I am wondering what the best (free preferred) sql query designers tools for Windows Vista are?

I am looking to create quite complicated INSERTS and UPDATES that involves joins etc and being a SQL beginner would like to use a tool to help design my queries a bit faster.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en

Comment: Thats what I am currently using but its not easy trying to create inserts unless I have totally missed it in there!  I was kind of looking for a wysiwyg type edit similar to the query edit in MS Studio Express you mention.  Will take another look at it.

Comment: right click table - script table as - insert to - new query editor window.  i've never heard of a wysiwyg for inserts.

Comment: damn, thats good! Thanks.  I never knew you could do that. I always created a new query, right click->Deisgn Query In Editor and when I selected multiple tables only got the option of SELECT.  How do I do INSERT for multiple tables?

Answer (score 1):

I favor Oracle [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) which supports many SQL databases, not just Oracle. SQL Developer has a lot of nice features, runs on all platforms, and the software is free.

Answer (score 0):

You might like [dbForge Query Builder for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/querybuilder/). It's not a freeware, but you can try 30-days trial.